# Command Line to find files in folder within folders in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-explorer, textfiles

I do this code in command line to find for series of files that has a .java property, then export in a textfile

```
dir *.java > output.txt
```

However there are still folders after the current folder, How can i FIND ALL THE files with .java starting from the current folder all the way to the folders after it.

Right now it is only showing results with the current folder I am in, but the the next or subfolder after it.

Answer (score 1):

append the `/s` parameter to your `dir` command:

```
dir /s *.java > export.txt
```